# Reading this site Rss

Tags: rss

I'm trying read [this site's Rss](http://alef.ir/rssb5.-er48r6--4qhfle2m.puirug.r.xml) using following code:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://alef.ir/rssew.skj1zjyss1rhx2k4m..9ji9b7.jbgjzqg.xml")
    Stream stream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
    XmlDocument rss = new XmlDocument();
    rss.Load(stream);
    XmlNodeList items = rss.SelectNodes("rss/channel/item");
```

.
.
.

But VS shows this problem:
The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

Comment: That just means the file's permissions on the server do not permit you to read it, and no amount of code you can write will change that. If it's your own server, you can change the permissions yourself. Otherwise, you'll have to ask the owner of the server.

Comment: But that is a rss! Permission for using rss?

Comment: It is a file on someone's server. Regardless of the type of file, every file has permissions that dictate who can do what with them. That particular file seems to be saying that your program is not allowed to read it. Which is weird because if you paste the url in the browser, it will load...

Answer (score 0):

It may have been temporary. Any time you have a problem getting a remote document programmatically you should go to the url in the browser and check if you can get it outside VS. I visited the url just now and had no problem getting the feed in my browser. You should not have problems to get that feed with VS now.